# Why does my javascript code rotate big images (>1MB)?

Tags: javascript, html, image, carousel, image-rotation

Hello and thanks in advance!
I created with some help the following code to display images out of a folder in kind of a slideshow. every minute the side will reload itself if nobody did something. this is to display new images while the slideshow is running. if the uploaded image is small (<1MB) the slideshow displays everything fine. But do I upload or copy larger images the slideshow flips or rotates the image sometime 180' or 90'.

here is the code:

```
<?php
$dir_path = "uploads/prints/";

$extensions_array = array('jpg','png','jpeg');

if(is_dir($dir_path))
{
$files = array_slice(scandir($dir_path), 2);
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    $ext = pathinfo($file);
    $ext = $ext['extension'];

    if(in_array($ext, $extensions_array))
        $images[] = '<img class="mySlides" src="'. $dir_path . $file.'" style="max-width:90%";>';
}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>automatic slideshow</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
.mySlides {display:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body background="/back2.png">

<!--<h2 class="w3-center">Automatic Slideshow</h2> -->
<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="width:500px">
<?php echo implode ($images); ?>
</div>


<script>
    var myIndex = 0;
    carousel();

    function carousel() {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");  
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";  
        }
        myIndex++;
        if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}   
        x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
        setTimeout(carousel, 4000); // Change image every 4 seconds
    }

//refresh page
 var timeout = setTimeout("location.reload(true);",60000);
  function resetTimeout() {
clearTimeout(timeout);
timeout = setTimeout("location.reload(true);",0000);    
  }     

</script>
</body>
```

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: Why do you think that your JS is rotating your images? Why do you think that your images are rotated at all?

Comment: cause it is displayed once upside down in the slideshow or rotated 90' 
when I take a photo with my iPhone and upload it, the slideshow will display it on its side. (bottom is side and side is bottom)

Comment: JPEGs can contain an EXIF orientation tag but afaik. all browsers at the moment ignore that. This tag defines how to transform the image to show it "correctly", relative to the orientation of the encoded data. [check these](/search?q=browser+exif+orientation)

Comment: thanks but I don´t know how to insert this part in my code... any hints?

Comment: Don't do this in the browser, just fix your images. Rotate them to the correct orientation, then optimize/minify them, and just then add them to your project.

Comment: they are in the right orientation... If I call the website via my iPhone browser the images are in the right orientation. If I call the images via browser direkt without a script, they are in the right orientation...

it seems that my script has some problems to display "large" images.. and I don´t know why...

for example: If I shoot a photo with a photo app like hipstermatic on my iPhone, call the upload page and upload the hipster-photo and the original (unhipster) photo, the hipster-photo is smaller and will be displayed right, the "large" original one will be rotated..  why´s that? :)

Comment: Nothing in this code will cause an image to rotate.  It might be something configured in the web server; I've heard of using squid proxies to flip images, for example.

Comment: **Your iPhone browser is doing it wrong!** The images themselves are rotated. **You have to fix the source images**, although hipstermatic seems to take care of that before uploading. Also check this question on the problem: [iOS 6 Safari Image Upload - Orientation Wrong](/questions/13055915/ios-6-safari-image-upload-orientation-wrong) and this answer fo a better solution: [Is it possible to perform a lossless rotation on a JPEG Image in PHP?](/a/3343400/6567275)